# EEVEE SSGI add-on question

Tags: add-on, eevee-render-engine

After trying out the [eevee ssgi add-on](https://gumroad.com/l/PgyXc), I started wondering if using the add-on is really necessary? Because you can just append the node groups to another project without needing to even install the add-on. The add-on really only is just a few sliders in the N menu, which can also be accessed in the node groups.

I'm mostly curious about this for the purposes of sending out projects to render farms which do not support add-ons.

aDd-oN

Comment: Honestly talking , i downloaded the SSGI yesterday to use it with a project and immediatly removed it after 1 glance....didnt like it , but if u get what you like with it , then u should really keep it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes true. That addon is not that necessary. Mostly all of addons doesn't make sense if we think that it can be done manually. But, add-ons are created with the soul purpose of making things easier than it is. If your render farm do not support the addons than it's up to you weather you want to use it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I have downloaded [SSGI add-on](https://gumroad.com/l/PgyXc) yesterday to use it for a project I work on and immediately removed it after some time playing around. I personally didn't like it but if you get what you want with it, keep it.Addons like this are not that Necessary because Addons do not implementing some new functionality, they are just taking 10 steps inside blender itself and shrinking them down to probably 2 and 3 clicks. I'm sure this would be also be possible to do using the built-in tools manually.

Talking about Render Farms which are paid per hour, don't getting the desired result compared to your viewport, then it is wasted money for sure but nothing that you can fix by yourself (as you mentioned) so I'd suggest do not use it in combination with render farms that actually don't support the add-on or ask the support team whether you can use it on their farm beforehand.

Comment: @brockmann,  will keep in mind

Comment: Just a suggestion, roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: Thsts actually better , tq @brockmann

Comment: Judging by your wording, I feel like you misunderstood my question. I'm not asking if it's necessary because it's a good add-on or not, but because you can use its functionalities without needing to install and use the add-on -- you can just append the node groups from another project, and get the same result -- or, that's what I'm actually curious about if that's true (though judging by my own testing, that does seem to be the case). Also I'm using the Sheepit renderfarm which is free.

Comment: @Geri if you are getting the same results then that really good and sheep it render farm is free , that's also good , by your question , yeah its not necessary and because you can append the node group from another project that works fine then you git th answer your self , that its not necessary …